Connecting MySQL Workbench to GCP
I have created MYSQL Instance on GCP.

I then added the IP Address of my laptop - 43.100...
Firewall permissions to for Ingres has been granted pass right with with an IP range of my computer IP address and tcp:3306 protocol on IAM GCP.
Public IP connectivity - Enabled on SQL Instance

WorkBench

I created a new database connection with a name vendor.
I added my GCP SQL Instance IP Address as a hostname 34.45..
username root with no password since my instance has no password.
port 3306
connection method standard (tcp/ip)
Tested connection and it fails every-time.

Error message : "Failed to connect MYSQL at 34.45..:3306 with user root"
"authentication plugin cannot be loaded. The specific module could not be loaded."


I tried recreating the SQL Instance multiple times and I keep getting the same error.
I also gave permission to the user to be the owner, editor and etc of the cloud SQL.
Public IP address is enabled.
Address is added to the list of addresses for connectivity



Try adding your MySQL Workbench machine's IP address as an authorized network for your Cloud SQL instance . In addition have a look at this document.

I have authorized the addresses.. see the image i added.
I included the ip range to cover all addresses on the network.

This error has nothing to do with network configuration as the error message says that certain authentication plugin cannot be loaded. You probably have a buggy version of mysql workbench.

Thank you. I managed to figure it out. Yes it has nothing to do with the network.
I reinstalled MySQL but used version  8.0.38 instead of  version 8.0.40 and then selected the authorization method as Use Legacy authorization method instead of the new method (Use strong password authentication "SHA256-based password".)
